# Select in Laravel not validate

Tags: php, html, laravel

This is my controller:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'surname1' => ['required', 'string'],
            'surname2' => ['required', 'string'],
            'comunidad_id' => ['required'],
            'provincia_id' => ['required'],
            'municipio_id' => ['required'],

        ]);
    }
```

this is my view blade:

```
<div class="form-group row">

    <label for="cbx_comunidad" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Seleccione Comunidad:
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select class="form-control @error('cbx_comunidad') is-invalid @enderror" name="cbx_comunidad" id="cbx_comunidad">
            <option>Seleccione Comunidad</option>
            <?php foreach ($comunidades as $comunidad): ?>
                <option value=<?php echo $comunidad['id'] ?>>
                    <?php echo $comunidad['comunidad'] ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
    @if($errors->has('cbx_comunidad'))
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
        <strong>{{ $errors->first('cbx_comunidad') }}</strong>
    </span> @endif
</div>
```

I need to know why laravel doesn't show me the error message when the field is empty, in Laravel 6.

Comment: Please can you show the controller method where your calling your `validator()` method.

Comment: It is register view the laravel auth. I don't know when is call a Laravel validator but other fiels in the same view, is validate correctly. for example surname1 is validate ok.

Comment: I don't see any validation for cbx_comunidad field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
'cbx_comunidad' => ['required']
```

to your validator on controller or change select options name like this

```
<select class="form-control @error('comunidad_id') is-invalid @enderror"
name="comunidad_id" id="cbx_comunidad" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this.

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
      @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
 </div>
@endif
```